# How do I get events in the X window system without pausing execution?

Tags: c++, events, x11

I need to get events from the X window system without pausing the execution of my program. Currently, I use `XNextEvent(dpy, &xev)` to get the events, but is there way to get events and run my own code simultaneously?

Comment: Did you try calling this function in another (dedicated) thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (XPending(dpy))
{
    XNextEvent(dpy, &e);
    switch (e.type) 
    {
        case Expose:
            break;
        // Manage events...
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

[XPending(Display *display)](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XPending.html) : Return the number of events in the Queue for the associated display.

You can remplace [XNextEvent(dpy, &e);](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/manipulating-event-queue/XNextEvent.html) by one of this functions, for get events only for specified Window / Mask or the two at same time :

1. XCheckTypedEvent();
2. XCheckTypedWindowEvent();
3. XcheckWindowEvent();

These 3functions are non-blocking.
For exemple, if you want to fecth event for a specified Window only, you can do :

```
while (XcheckWindowEvent(dpy, window, your_event_mask, &e))
{
    switch (e.type) 
    {
        case Expose:
            break;
        // Manage events...
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

PS : Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Thank you. Do you know any function like these that do also apply to fullscreen applications?

Comment: These functions works well in Windows with FullScreen mode.
Maybe you ask how to get a FullScreen window?